# How to avoid follow-mode large text spillovers to the next windows when the text size is decreased?

Tags: windows, emacs, font-size

When setting my `text-scale-mode-amount` to `-2` i.e <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C--</kbd><kbd>C--</kbd> and using `follow-mode` alongside I get this annoying large amounts(20 lines) of text spillover in the next buffer which almost defeats the main purpose of using `follow-mode`. The spillover increases when the `text-scale-mode-amount` is further decreased(further decreasing the size of the text).

Any solutions to this?

**Update 1:**

Just tested this on my Emacs running on Ubuntu(Linux) and nothing of that sort happens. No spillovers. Its the Windows Emacs that is causing the problem.

**Update 2:**

Its a bug that is occurring in *GNU Emacs 24.2.1 (i386-mingw-nt6.1.7600) of 2012-08-29 on MARVIN* and seems to have been fixed in *Emacs 24.3* since I am not facing the problem after upgrading to it. Therefore this question is specific to the above mentioned version of Emacs and others facing the same.

Comment: You should probably post and accept update 2 as the answer.

Comment: @phils but that wouldn't be helpful to someone who at present or in future faces this problem and doesn't have the option of upgrade his/her Emacs. Couldn't find any related bug [in](http://debbugs.gnu.org) so that I could state its fix in the answer.

Comment: Hmmm... upgrading software to fix bugs *is* a fairly common solution; however, you could always grab `follow.el*` out of the Emacs 24.3 distribution, pop it somewhere in your personal load path for Emacs 24.2, verify whether it works as-is in that version (which is pretty likely), and if so then recommend that anyone who can't upgrade Emacs for any reason simply do the same.

Comment: @phils just did what you suggested and you are right. Replacing the built-in one with the `follow.el` from the latest version of Emacs actual does solve the problem. Question answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Simple solution:**

Like [phils](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17169357/how-to-avoid-follow-mode-large-text-spillovers-to-the-next-windows-when-the-text#comment24899435_17169357) suggested, upgrade the Emacs.

**Not so simple solution:**

Replace `Emacs_installation_dir/lisp/follow.el` with [`this`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/plain/lisp/follow.el?h=emacs-24&id=3a1ce0685f66f5fb162b07f6bf4a1d8e1ec75c06) and delete `follow.elc` in the same directory. Or force Emacs to use the above package instead of the built-in one(overriding it).

Comment: If replacing the file, I would also recommend using `M-x byte-compile-file` to compile the replacement follow.el file, otherwise its performance will suffer unnecessarily.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a bug in follow-mode which doesn't really pay attention to the actual text displayed.  I'd recommend a `report-emacs-bug` to get a bug-number for that issue.